# How to empty form fields after using in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

i'm currently studying laravel, and experimenting on forms. I'm using the Laravel Collective. In my controller, I have the following code.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

When one of the fields is empty, it redirects back to the form and the previous value of the field is kept. For example, if I fill in `This is a title` in the title field, and leave the body empty, validation fails and the form redirects back to itself and the value of title is `This is a title` Is there a way for all (or specific fields) to be empty when the validation has failed? Thank you.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/form-validation-how-to-disable-showing-validation-errors

Comment: Are you aware that keeping the inputs is a feature and not a bug?

Comment: I know it's a feature, i never said anything being a bug. I'm just trying to experiment, and if I had more time to study, I would've researched instead of asking here.

Comment: Asking here should be the last resort after a fair amount of researching.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#old-input)

In your `*.blade.php` you may find something that looks like:

`<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">`

You'll just need to remove the value from the HTML and it won't be kept.

Comment: actually I was using form helper, and the default value was already at ' '. The comment above however suggested to make a  custom validation so that I can run a `redirect()->withInput($request->except('title'))`. Thank you though! :)

Comment: Laravel collective automatically does this for you as shown in their documentation, you did not post your blade code, so I took an educated guess. Anyway, glad it's solved. Please include the whole question next time.